# Typescript: how I can use array of functons?

Tags: typescript

In the below code, `onResizeWindowHandles` has type `any`, but must be the array of functions:

```
export default class PageLayoutManager {

  private $Window: JQuery<Window>;
  private onResizeWindowHandlers: any;

  constructor () {
    this.$Window = $(window);

    this.handleWindowResize();
    this.onResizeWindowHandlers = new Array();
  }

  public addWindowOnResizeHandler(newHandler: any): void {
    this.onResizeWindowHandlers.push(newHandler);
  }

  private handleWindowResize(): void {
    this.$Window.on('resize', () => {
      this.onResizeWindowHandlers.forEach(handlerFunction => {
        handlerFunction();
      })
    });
  }
}
```

How I can correctly set the type for `onResizeWindowHandles`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Array class with the Function class in the generics, like this:

```
private onResizeWindowHandlers: Array<Function>;
```

Comment: Very laconic solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax for typing a function, using a type alias

```
type MyFunc = (arg1: number, arg2: string) => boolean
```

Alternatively, as an interface:

```
interface MyFunc {
  (arg1: number, arg2: string): boolean
}
```

Either work, but I prefer the type alias. It's a little more succinct and readable.

In your case, `() => void` is probably the most fitting, seeing as the function is being called without arguments, and the return type is unused.

```
type ResizeHandler = () => void

export default class PageLayoutManager {
  private onResizeWindowHandlers: ResizeHandler[]

  constructor () {
    this.onResizeWindowHandlers = [] // as an aside, use `[]` instead of `new Array()`
  }

  public addWindowOnResizeHandler(newHandler: ResizeHandler): void {
    this.onResizeWindowHandlers.push(newHandler)
  }
}
```

The type `Function` would also work here, but it's basically the same as `(...args: any[]) => any`, which isn't very type safe and should generally be avoided.